# Why I have SQLite null pointer when notification is received?

Tags: android, sqlite, push-notification

I am building an app where I am using Firebase notifications. I want, when notification is received, to save that notification in local storage(SQLite). But When I want to read from that database it sends me null pointer. Where is my mistake?

Here is my DataBaseHelper class:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bazaFire.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Messages";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME="message_body";
private SQLiteDatabase myDB;
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
            + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, message_body TEXT)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}
public void insertMsg(String msg) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d("getWritable", "Okay");

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, msg);
    Log.d("Stavljena", msg);

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

    db.close();

}
public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy){
    return myDB.query("Messages", null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Here is myFirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class myFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG="MyFirebaseMsgService";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d("onMessageReceived", "Pozvana funkcija onMessageReceived");
    Log.d(TAG, "From " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Body " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    Log.d(TAG, "Location " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction());
    Log.d(TAG, "Value " + remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action"));
    sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    Log.d("Function called", "sendNotification");
    String message=remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    Log.d("baza", message);
    DataBaseHelper db=new DataBaseHelper(this);
    db.insertMsg(message);


}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(myFirebaseMessagingService.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("click_action", "goToFragment1");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(logo)
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build());
}
```

And here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button dugme, dugme2, dugme3;
Cursor c;
DataBaseHelper db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("onCreate", "ONCREATE");
    final Intent intent=getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String msg = getIntent().getStringExtra("click_action");
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


    if (msg != null) {
        if (msg.equals("goToFragment1")) {
            Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment1);
            Log.d("FragmentTransaction", "Fragment je promenjen u onCreate!");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            Log.d("Create", "Kraj onCreatea");
        }
    }

    dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme1);
    dugme2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribe);
    dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if (view == dugme) {
                fragment = new Fragment1();
            }
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });


    dugme2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("android");
            Log.d("Log", "Uspesno ste se pretplatili");
        }
    });
    try{
    c=db.query("Messages", null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){

        do{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "id: " + c.getString(0) + "IME: " + c.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        while(c.moveToNext());{

        }


    }}catch (Exception e){
        throw new Error("Greska!");
    }
```

And this is my logcat:

```
06-15 14:36:26.354 29325-29325/com.example.dev3.notifikacijefragmenti E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    java.lang.Error: Greska!
                                                                                        at com.example.dev3.notifikacijefragmenti.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post the original Exception Stacktrace?

Comment: Is this question still valid? Did the answer below not solved your problem?

Comment: Well, that answer did not help me, but I fix the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you've never instantiated your `DataBaseHelper` class in `MainActivity`.

When you are trying to call the following:

```
c=db.query("Messages", null, null, null, null, null);
```

`db` is still `null`.

Add the following line in `onCreate()`:

```
db = new DataBaseHelper();
```